# DPDK with AF_XDP: Failed to create xsk socket

Tags: linux, xdp-bpf

I am trying to run AF_XDP poll mode driver. Kernel Version is 5.4(CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS=y).
When i run the samples provided by DPDK website, an error was happened.

```
root@n211-203-164:~# dpdk-testpmd --vdev=net_af_xdp0,iface=eth3 -- -i --total-num-mbufs=10240
EAL: Detected 96 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available 1048576 kB hugepages reported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:5e:00.0 (socket 0)
mlx5_net: Default miss action is not supported.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:5e:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_net: Default miss action is not supported.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:86:00.0 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: Default miss action is not supported.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:86:00.1 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: Default miss action is not supported.
Interactive-mode selected
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=10240, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_1>: n=10240, size=2176, socket=1
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc

Warning! port-topology=paired and odd forward ports number, the last port will pair with itself.

Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: B8:CE:F6:35:DB:3A
Configuring Port 1 (socket 0)
Port 1: B8:CE:F6:35:DB:3B
Configuring Port 2 (socket 1)
Port 2: B8:CE:F6:3B:31:4A
Configuring Port 3 (socket 1)
Port 3: B8:CE:F6:3B:31:4B
Configuring Port 4 (socket 0)
xsk_configure(): Failed to create xsk socket.
eth_rx_queue_setup(): Failed to configure xdp socket
Fail to configure port 4 rx queues
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Start ports failed
```

it seems that XSK socket call bind() failed and eth_rx_queue_setup() failed as a result.

How to correctly configure EAL parameters to run dpdk-testpmd with vdev=af_net_xdp0? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Icl1996, can you please help yo understand the following `1. are you binding mlx5_net 4 NIC ports with IGB_uio? 2) what is the result for lshw -c net -businfo, 3) is eth3 port link up? 4) is eth3 part of mlx5 nic ports? 5) Is there already an XDP program on the? 6) if you do not plan to use 0000:5e:00.X, please re-run with DPDk option --no-pci and share the result. 7) also share the DPDK version`

Comment: @VipinVarghese 1. NIC ports are all bound by mlx5_core，not IGB_uio.   2. Bus info          Device    Class          Description
======================================================
pci@0000:5e:00.0  eth0      network        MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]
pci@0000:5e:00.1  eth1      network        MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]
pci@0000:86:00.0  eth2      network        MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]
pci@0000:86:00.1  eth3      network        MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5].     3. eth3 link status is up 4. eth3 is mlx5 nic port 5.  no XDP program on eth3.   7. 21.08

Comment: Thanks for the update, if the eth3 is not bound with vfio-pci or igb_uio. then the option for running `--vdev=net_af_xdp0,iface=eth3 ` is correct. Since `eth3` is `0000:86:00.1`. requesting to check `current kernel NIC driver support XDP` for the device and Linux kernel is build to support XDP via ` egrep "BPF|XDP"  /boot/config-$(uname -r)`?

Comment: Please also check https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/networking/device_drivers/mellanox/mlx5.html `CONFIG_MLX5_CORE=y/m and CONFIG_MLX5_CORE_EN=y.` using ` grep CONFIG_MLX5 /boot/config-$(uname -r)`. Can you please sahre the MTU size configured on `eth3`. There were proposal for support 4K above MTU, I think it is integrated in Linux kernel 5.12 only. Please check MTU with `ifconfig eht3 | grep -i mtu

Comment: @VipinVarghese Much thanks for your help. The root cause is about RLIMIT_MEMLOCK. When i add setrlimit into libbpf.so and replace the old one, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @Icl1996 happy to hear the problem is solved, was really confused when it was mentioned DPDK is not able to run XDP PMD or has issues. Hence ventured in to help to resolve DPDK related issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue about rlimit. I wrote a simple test programer.

```
#include <bpf.h>
#include <xsk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <sys/resource.h>

//static struct rlimit r = {RLIM_INFINITY, RLIM_INFINITY};

int main() {
        //setrlimit(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, & r);

        int fd = bpf_create_map_name(BPF_MAP_TYPE_XSKMAP, "xsks_map", sizeof(int), sizeof(int), 1, 0);
        printf("fd:%d\n", fd);
        return 0;
}
```

Execute cmd `strace -e bpf ./test-prog` and the result could be like this:

```
root@n211-203-164:~# strace -e bpf ./test 
bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=0x11 /* BPF_MAP_TYPE_??? */, key_size=4, value_size=4, max_entries=1}, 112) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fd:-1 1
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

This means `max locked memory` caused the insufficient resource allocation.
Execute cmd `ulimit -a` could find `max locked memory` is 64 kbytes.
There are 2 solutions, one is to enlarge `max locked memory` globally by executing cmd `ulimit -S -l <a big value>`, and the other is to call setrlimit() into libbpf.so when creating a BPF map.